# how to rewrite history to remove executable bit in git

Tags: windows, git, executable, git-filter-branch

I have imported a rather large repository from another SCM into git. Unfortunately the migration was done (had to be) on Windows and every file got committed into git with the execute bit set. To avoid having to do the migration again (it is a long and hang-prone process) I am trying to figure out if I can clean out the executable bit server side. My thought is using git filter-branch somehow combined with git update-index, but I could take hints as to how to proceed.

Doing a huge commit at the end clearing all executable bits is not a solution -- I don't want every file to have a bump in the history.

Comment: This seems to do the trick:

    git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s  | sed s/^100755/10644/ | git update-index --index-info' -- --all

Comment: You should post that as an answer that you will be able then to (auto-)accept. This seems a really nice trick and doesn't seem documented elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't do that for the first eight hours. Sometimes I don't understand the rules of this game. ;)

Comment: All the rules are there: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange. In your case: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86185/minimum-reputation-for-answering-your-own-question-should-be-higher-than-what-is/86186#86186. Once you hit 100 rep, you're in the clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```bsh
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s  |
                                  sed s/^100755/10644/ |
                                  git update-index --index-info' -- --all
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is quite good, but there is another possibility: `git config core.filemode false`:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

> core.fileMode
>
> If false, the executable bit differences between the index and the working copy are ignored; useful on broken filesystems like FAT. See git-update-index(1).
>
> The default is true, except git-clone(1) or git-init(1) will probe and set core.fileMode false if appropriate when the repository is created.

This may create more work for everyone who has to clone the repo in the future (or it may not, I'm not really sure), so your solution is probably better, but I thought I'd throw this out there as it may be more appropriate for someone else's use case...

Comment: Files that are already checked in with the executable bit won't be helped by this. They will have the executable bit set when checked out anyway. core.filemode = false would have prevented this happening in the first place, though. IMHO it should be the default on Windows.

I should underline that rewriting history is incredibly useful on an initial import, which is what I am doing now, but of course questionable after you have put the repository into production.

Comment: Edit file and do `chmod -R -x+X *`. Now add/commit/push the executable bits.